# PHP - Getting the html code after end of tag intro a string

Tags: php, html

I've got this code from a html file, which some users can upload. Every file must have a `<div>` with `class="footer"`. I need to get the html code after the footer's `</div>` tag and save it in a variable. For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<title>Dodmond</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link href="layout/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
<body id="top">
<div class="header">
header content
</div>
<div class="content">
content
</div>
<div class="footer">
footer content
</div>
<a id="backtotop" href="#top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
<!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.backtotop.js"></script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a html file from a user and I need something like

`$codeAfterLayout = '<a id="backtotop" href="#top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"</i></a><!-- JAVASCRIPTS --> <script src="layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"
</script><script src="layout/scripts/jquery.backtotop.js"></script><script src="layout/scripts/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script><script src="layout/scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script></body'`

I managed using DOM to remove all the divs, but still remaining the code before first `<div>` :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<title>Dodmond</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link href="layout/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
<body id="top">
```

Some idea how to save only the html code after the footer's `</div>` tag?

**PHP Code**

```
$html = file_get_contents($path);
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new \DomXPath($doc);
$divs = $finder->query('//div');        
foreach ($finder->evaluate('//div') as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get the code"?  What does this have to do with PHP?  Please clarify what you're asking.

Comment: @David Is that better?

Comment: Are you asking how to view the JavaScript code being linked in those `<script>` elements?  Something else?  Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @David Another edit. I just need to get that code in a variable (a string).

Comment: So you have a string which contains HTML, and you need to parse a specific sub-string from it?  What you're looking for is called a DOM parser.  There are a variety of tools to use, a Google search for something like "php dom parser" will provide some common options.

Comment: @David Yes, I am already using DOM parser, but still can't get to that code.

Comment: Then you'll probably want to include the code you're using and the specific problem you're encountering.  We can't actually see your screen from here, so there's not much we can tell you about code you're not showing us.

Comment: @David Is it good enough? I don't know how else to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Is the HTML code from your view or other website?

You can try to use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function to get HTML as a string, and then parse the string.